# Java8 - Convert Integer array to multiple list of single element

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have an array of which I want to create List with each list have only one element of array.
So for array {1,2,3} I want to create 3 List with each having element 1, 2 and 3 respectively.

Have done it using java 7 but wanted to know if it can be solved using java 8 stream, maps etc

Thanks

Comment: It’s not very hard, using the basics shown in the documentation: for `Integer[]`, you can use `List<List<Integer>> list = Arrays.stream(array).map(Collections::singletonList).collect(Collectors.toList());`, for an `int[]`, you only have to change `map` to `mapToObj`…

Comment: @Holger Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will work:

```
Integer[] array = {1,2,3};

List<List<Integer>> list = Arrays.stream(array)
                                 .map(Collections::singletonList)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank u, was missing Collections::singletonList part.